# Property '__super__' does not exist on type '(pointSimplifierIns: any, opts: any) => void'

Tags: webpack, build, point, massive

I use the Scott map in the angular2 project of mass point API，When I run
 `npm run build:prod` An error has occurred，The following is a relevant code and exceptions （added：There is no question of `npm start` command）

```
/**
   * Custom grouping rendering engine, for example, only function similar to
     PointSimplifier.Render.Canvas.GroupStyleRender
   * @param {PointSimplifier} pointSimplifierIns The associated
     PointSimplifier instance
   * @param {Object} opts   configuration
   */
  function MyCanvasRender(pointSimplifierIns, opts) {
    // Direct call the superclass constructor
    MyCanvasRender.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
  }
```

error info：

```
[at-loader] Checking started in a separate process...
```

[at-loader] Checking finished with 6 errors
Error in bail mode: [at-loader] ./src/app/pages/map/massive/massive.component.ts:39:24
    TS2339: Property '**super**' does not exist on type '(pointSimplifierIns: any, opts: any) => void'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8k6h.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eDEps.png)

Comment: Images of code are not accessible, they aren't searchable (which is how someone else with the same problem might stumble on this question), and they are really hard to read on phones. Please [edit] the question and put the code and error messages in as text and then use the code format button in the editor.